# Coredata update issue

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, crash, migration

So i had two `.xcdatamodel` in my iPad app which is on Appstore . each consisting of 6 and 4 entities each.

for `model2.xcdatamodel` i had configuration:@"sort-config"

both these models has no versioning and nothing and made default data sources. (i was starting those days).

This was on Appstore.

Now i am about to update my iOS app and

now i ahve 3 .xcdatamodel

i had added the `model3.xcdatamodel` and changed the last

```
model2.xcdatamodel 
configuration:@"sort-config"
```

to nil.

now when i try to update Appstore app, with this app using same AppId and development version provisional profile, i get error

`"reason=Can't find model for source store} with userInfo dictionary"`.

I am pretty sure i didn't change anything in last two model. neither i removed or added any library.

I went went back to last Appstore commit in git and took a checkout. cant seem to find any difference.

Please let me know what could i do in this case.

Comment: If you don't have versioning how did you expect it to work seeing as making changes and upgrading requires versioning

Comment: Because i know there wont be any change in the first two xcdatamodel.
They were never meant to be changed.
Adding a new xcdatamodel doesn't effect the last datamodels does it ?

Comment: and still there is no change in the first two data models.

Comment: Why so many data models?

Comment: Its a finance app, so different types of data i saaved.
the first model save various dictionaries
the 2nd model save Graph array points.

the third model (new) is made for noteboook.

Comment: My question is  , I haven't given any version to model while submitting thining i wont change it. 
I added third model and it shows me error. 
How to resolve this ?

Comment: First I would recommend choosing human readable/understandable names for your models. Secondly, maybe include how you are trying to instantiate the model and where it breaks so its easier to help you